# C# gui the mouse move event cannot select a list element?

Tags: c#, user-interface, drawing, gdi+

This title might be a bit not precise, what I am really having is this issue. I plotted a few lines, each is stored in a list, as line path. Then I use `IsOutlineVisible` to measure if the mouse location is on any of them, if mouse is on one, draw it as a different color or do something.
But it only recognize the last line in the list.

I would attach only the relevant part of the code, but this I really am not too sure where is the problem, so here is the entire code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup = new List<GraphicsPath>();
    Point Latest{get;set;}
   List<Point> pointtemp = new List<Point>();
   bool startdrawline = true;
   bool selectlinestate = false;
   int selectedline;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the mouse coordinates
        Latest = new Point(e.X, e.Y);

        // Force to invalidate the form client area and immediately redraw itself. 
        Refresh();

        if (startdrawline == false)
        {
            selectedline = Linesel(LineGroup);
        }

    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        var g = e.Graphics;
        base.OnPaint(e);



        Pen penb = new Pen(Color.Navy,2);
        Pen peny=new Pen(Color.Yellow,2);


                    for (int i = 0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == selectedline)
            {
                g.DrawPath(peny, LineGroup[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawPath(penb, LineGroup[i]);
            }
        }
        penb.Dispose();
        peny.Dispose();



        if (startdrawline == true)
        {
            GraphicsPath tracepath = new GraphicsPath();
            Pen penr = new Pen(Color.Red,2);

            if (pointtemp.Count == 1)
            {
                tracepath.AddLine(pointtemp[0], Latest);

            }
            else if (pointtemp.Count > 1)
            {
                tracepath.AddLine(pointtemp[1], Latest);
            }

            g.DrawPath(penr, tracepath);
            penr.Dispose();

        }
        Refresh();

    }







    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {



        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            startdrawline = false;
            pointtemp.Clear();
        }
        else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left )
        {
            startdrawline = true;


            Latest = new Point(e.X, e.Y);


            if (pointtemp.Count < 2)
            {
                pointtemp.Add(Latest);
            }
            else
            {
                pointtemp[0] = pointtemp[1];
                pointtemp[1] = Latest;


            }


            if (pointtemp.Count == 2)
            {
                LineP2P(pointtemp);
            }


            Refresh();
        }

    }




    private void LineP2P(List<Point> pointtemp){
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddLine(pointtemp[0], pointtemp[1]);
        LineGroup.Add(path);

    }


 private int  Linesel(List<GraphicsPath> LineGroup)
    {
        int selectedline=-1;
        for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
        {
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
            if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            {
                selectedline = i;

            }
            else if (!LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            {
                selectedline = -1;

            }
            label1.Text = selectedline.ToString();
        }
        return selectedline;
    }



}
}
```

When I put the test label.Text under the if

```
if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
            {
                selectedline = i;
                label1.Text = selectedline.ToString();
            }
```

it actually works (varies with lines)
Can anyone identify the cause? Lot of Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not break out of the loop once you find your line

lets say the line your mouse is on is at index 0. You are going to call
`selectedline = 0` on the first iteration
and then on the second iteration

```
if (LineGroup[1].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
```

would be false so

```
selectedline = -1;
```

Thus unless you are mouse is on the last line selectedline will always be -1

What you want to do is probably

```
    selectedline = -1;
    for (int i =0; i < LineGroup.Count; i++)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Navy, 8);
        if (LineGroup[i].IsOutlineVisible(Latest, pen))
        {
            selectedline = i;
            break;

        }
    }

    label1.Text = selectedline.ToString();
    return selectedline;
```